# WPF Replace a ComboBox with a PopUp with WrapPanel

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, wrappanel

I have the task of replacing basic ComboBox and its items with a more pleasing UI design.

I have to be able to allow the user to select (a) a single item in one case or (b) several in another (essentially the user is building a query using (a) a simple "=" or (b) the operator "in" according to their wishes.

I think creating a PopUp with an ItemsControl/WrapPanel would be the best solution starting with this:

```
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

[image: Screenshot] This shows roughly how it should look

**My question is** how to solidly allow this to accept *one* single selected item at a time to cover situation (a) above. I'd like a "SelectedItem" property I suppose.

(In situation (b) I plan to use Checkboxes).

Many thanks.

Comment: Use ListBox with SelectionMode.Single and WrappPanel as ItemsPanel

Comment: Post this as an answer and I'll mark it as such!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ListBox with SelectionMode.Single and WrappPanel as ItemsPanel

Comment: Thanks. The simplest of solutions once again!